# Prevent a public service from overusing

Tags: c#, security, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service

I have a web api 2 that I want to host on azure-app-service. The service should be called by javascript applications so as far as I know it has to be open to public (right?).

However, if I let it be totally open it is vulnerable to DOS. What is the best way to do that?

The first thing that came to my mind was to implement a custom IP Filter that keeps requests from last x minutes and let the one with less than y occurrence pass.

Is there any other way? Is there any specific way to do it on the azure without writing code?

---

**This is not a broad question! I think it is clear what I am asking! 
I have a service on Azure and I want to protect it from overusing. How broad is that?!?!**

Comment: cloudfare or similar services?

Comment: @4c74356b41 sorry I didn't get your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a public API (ie. something a mobile app would talk to), it has to be.. well, public of course. :)

If your users have to sign up before consuming your API (or if this is an option), you could use API keys. That does not prevent DoS, and is not a form of authentication if given to clients, but at least you can quickly revoke offending keys to somewhat mitigate DoS.

Other than that, your primary concern with regard to DoS is application level DoS. You should try to avoid API calls that put a strain on your backend, limit response sizes (which probably implies paging on a client), etc. With these things done in your API, let your provider deal with the network level stuff.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want to use my service as a signup service. so if you sign up you will receive an email. Now, a person can go and use my service thousands of times in 1 day and I will end up will a db full of unwanted data, and an email server that has been categorized as a spam creator

Comment: You can rate-limit your sign up action for a given client IP and not let it invoke sign up too frequently. This also depends on whether your typical clients are behind NAT (typical corporate users) or not (typical home users). You should also not have any user content in emails sent, so there is less point in using others' email addresses to sign up. You should not send too many emails to the same address. These would probably help mitigate the risk you described (which is very valid btw).

Comment: Hi again, I am trying to set the rate limit on my azure portal now. but here it says that I need to pay 50$ for api management service (developer) and 700$ for standard one, which is 10 times more expensive than my production environment :(. Am I in the right place? is there any cheaper options?

Answer (score 1):

By default azure services are protected against DDOS,MITM attacks and all communication is via https and encrypted.

As far the application design goes you need to take care of the following ;
SQL Injection,Session hijacking, Cross-site-scripting, Application-level MITM and Application-level DDoS.

Further you can do vulnerability check on your app services using Tinfoil security scanning tests. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/web-vulnerability-scanning-for-azure-app-service-powered-by-tinfoil-security/

Also using azure API management service you can use the API gateway to control API calls, routing, enforce usage quotas and also do throttling based on the traffic to the API.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-product-with-rules/

Comment: Thanks for response, I am trying to set the rate limit on my azure portal now. but here it says that I need to pay 50$ for api management service (developer) and 700$ for standard one, which is 10 times more expensive than my production environment :(. Am I in the right place? is there any cheaper options?

Comment: yeah that's the rate as such. Or you can try other api management products like 3scale,app42 etc. may be they are cheaper. but not sure of azure integration.